# Reverting to earlier version without access to remote server?

Tags: git

I completed my project in university, but after graduation I no longer have access to the remote git server we used.

If I want to revert to an earlier version, can I still do so ? Will my local folder have all commits saved ? How would I do it?

Comment: Git is decentralized, you will have the entire repo locally provided that you saved the '.git' folder. Try `git log` too see the history (or use a UI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted that you have a recent enough version of the repo*, **yes**, that's one of the great aspects of git : **your repo has everything**.

If you search in your local repo for branches and commits (through `git branch` and `git log` with different options, mostly), you'll be able to inspect and restore any past point of your project history without relying on any connection to a central remote server.

* *(when was the last time you fetched from remote? Pulls count too, since it fetches in the background)*

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean even project members who joined late in the project, will still have access to all commits?

Comment: @KaizerSozay Yes. Unless their last fetched version is too old for some recent work, they essentially have everything.

Comment: I’m confused by your * comment. I guess you mean I should have all commits up till my last pull?

Comment: I meant that if someone added anything to the repo at your university (the one you don't have acces to any more) *after* your last fetch/pull, you wan't have *that*. But you have everything else.

Comment: Yeah that’s fine. The server doesn’t exist anymore because class is over, so I have the last commit.